Discrete G-module iff union over submodules fixed by open subgroups
I am working through Weibel's homological algebra and got stuck on a seemingly simple exercise, 6.11.6. We say that a $G$-module $A$ is discrete if the $G$-action is continuous when $A$ is endowed with the discrete topology.
This states that a $G$-module $A$ is discrete iff it can be written as the union $A = \bigcup A^U$ over all open subgroups of $G$. One implication is clear, but I can't seem to conclude that $A$ is a discrete $G$-module when it can be written in this manner.
I have tried rewriting the stabilizer of an element $a \in A$ (continuity of the action is equivalent to the stabilizers being open) but to no avail. Then I thought that maybe $\operatorname{Stab}(a) = \bigcup_{U: a\in A^U} U$ but only managed to prove one of these implications as I can't seem to conclude that if $g$ stabilizes $a$, then it is contained in some open subgroup $U$ such that $a \in A^U$.

Does this help? Welcome to the site

@FShrike Thank you! I have seen this post but they simply state this, without a proof.

I haven't fully thought this through but observe if $A$ carries the discrete topology, ${a}$ is open so the preimage $\mu^{-1}{a}$ is an open subset of $G\times A=\bigsqcup_{b\in A}G$ i.e. for each $b$ fixed, ${g\in G:gb=a}$ is open in $G$

@FShrike Yes, but this is under the assumption that our action $\mu$ is continuous, which is what I need to prove.

To show that any stabilizer is open, note that $a \in A^U$ for some open subgroup $U$ implies that $U$ is contained in $\mathrm{Stab}(a)$. Now we can write $\mathrm{Stab}(a)=\bigcup_{x \in \mathrm{Stab}(a)} xU$, thus $\mathrm{Stab}(a)$ is open. (More generally this shows that in topological group, a subgroup containing any non-empty open subset is open)
